# kendo ui grid crud with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, kendo-grid

1. pleas help me with sample kendo grid with codeigniter controller

   ## my view

   ```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: {
       transport: {
           read: {
               url: 'schoolC/crud',
               contentType: 'application/json'
           },
           create: {
               url: 'schoolC/crud',
               type: "PUT",
               datatype: 'json'
           },
           update: {
               url: 'schoolC/crud',
               type: "POST",
               datatype: 'json'
           },
           destroy: {
               url: 'schoolC/crud',
               type: "POST",
               datatype: 'json'
           }                                
       },
       error: function(e) {
               alert(e.responseText);
           },
       schema: {
           data: "data",
           id: "school_id",
           model: {
               fields: {
                   school_name: { 
                       type: "string",
                       validation: { required: true }
                   }
               }
           }
       },
       pageSize: 10
   },
   height: 400,
   batch: false,
   scrollable: true,
   sortable: true,
   filterable: true,
   resizable: true,
   toolbar: ['create'],
   editable: "popup",
   pageable: {                            
       numeric: true,
       refresh: true,
       pageSizes: true
   }, 
   columns: [
       {
           field: "school_name",
           title: "School Name",                                
           width: 100
       },
       { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "210px" }                            
   ]
   ```

   });

   ## Controller method

   ```
   function crud()
   {
       header("Content-type: application/json");
       switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])
       {
           case 'GET':
               echo $this->SchoolM->get_allJsonData(); 
           break;
           case 'PUT':
               echo $this->SchoolM->addSchoolInfo(array('school_name'=> mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["school_name"])));
           break;
           case 'POST':
               echo $this->SchoolM->updateSchoolInfo(array('school_name'=> mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["school_name"])), array('school_id'=> mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["school_id"])));
           break;
           case 'DELETE':
               echo $this->SchoolM->deleteSchool(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["school_id"]));               
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

   ## Model methods

   ```
   function get_allJsonData()
   {
       $arr = array();
       $this->db->from('school');
       $this->db->order_by("school_name", "asc");
       $query = $this->db->get();
       foreach($query->result_object() as $rows )
       {
           $arr[] = $rows;
       }
       return "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";
   }
   function addSchoolInfo($school_name)
   {
       return json_encode($this->db->insert('school',$school_name));
   } 
   function updateSchoolInfo($school_date, $condition)
   {
       return json_encode($this->db->update('school', $school_date, $condition));
   }
   function deleteSchool($school_id)
   {
       $this->db->where_in('school_id',$school_id);
       return json_encode($this->db->delete('school'));
   }
   ```

   i am using codeigniter it read but the rest create update and delete are not properly work. It also add many empty rows as the size of the rows in each create operation.pls help me

Answer (score 0):

sorry do not know english, auto translate this working here, lol.
But I think I can help you, you are struggling to make their calls CRUD in your GRID?

What I did was create all with the same call, but with a GET if passed by reference to what will be done. See the example below.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport:{
                read: "CRUD.client.php?func=read",
                create: {
                    url: "CRUD.client.php?func=create",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "CRUD.client.php?func=update",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "CRUD.client.php?func=delete",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
```

> Note that once the file, which is the same for all, has a passing parameters that php will read and decide who will be execudado alert by if.

```
if ($verb == "GET" && $func == "read") {code CRUD here}
```

I have helped!!!